# Using cvReshape after convertion from IplImage to CvMat by cvGetImage

Tags: opencv, reshape, iplimage

I need to get 1D vectors from input grayscale images in order to calculate covariance matrix. So I'm trying to convert IplImage to CvMat and then reshape it.

At the first time I used the following code:

```
CvMat *image_matrix = cvCreateMat(image->width, image->height, CV_32FC1);
cvConvert(image, image_matrix);
CvMat iv_p, *image_vector = cvCreateMat(image->widht * image->height, 1, CV_32FC1);
image_vector = cvReshape(image_matrix, &iv_p, 1, image->widht * image->height);
```

But it gave me

> Assertion failed (src.size == dst.size && src.channels<> ==
>   dst.channels<> in cvConvertScale)

So I find here another way:

```
CvMat i_p, *image_matrix;
image_matrix = cvGetMat(image, &i_p, 0, 0);
CvMat iv_p, *image_vector = cvCreateMat(image->widht * image->height, 1, CV_32FC1);
image_vector = cvReshape(image_matrix, &iv_p, 1, image->widht * image->height);
```

But this time I get

> Image step is wrong (The matrix is not continuous, thus the number of rows can not be changed> in cvReshape.

Could anybody please suggest any solution to my problem?

Comment: ohh, please, use the c++ api instead.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm just starting to learn opencv and unfortunately find only lessons with old interface. Could the usage of c++ fix this problem?

Comment: yea, it's pretty bad that you mostly find outdated examples, also that ppl here on SO are quite happy with their ignorance. the c++ api will definitely solve your 1st problem (as you don't have to manually allocate 'output' Mat's.